# Contador não atualiza dados na pagina usando ReactJS e useState(), somente quando coloco um console.log() que consigo ver o resultado

Tags: javascript, react

estou fazendo um curso de ReactJs, e estou tentando seguir todos os exemplos de código, porém meu código esta igual ao do instrutor e mesmo assim meu não esta funcionando igual o dele. Toda vez que for clicado em incrementar chama-se uma função para que realize uma conta básica e usa o useState para atualizar o valor do array, mas mesmo assim na minha tela no navegador ao clicar no button continua sem atualizar e se eu colocar um console.log() eu consigo ver que a cada click no button o valor soma mais 1.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Header from './Header'

function App() {
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0)

  function increment() {
    setCounter(count + 1);
    console.log(count)
  }

  return (
    <div>
       <Header>Contador: {count}</Header>
       <button onClick={increment}>Incrementar</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: print do código e do resultado]

Comment: Podes mostrar o teu `<Header>`? O teu código funciona para mim... https://jsfiddle.net/j81Le92q/

Comment: tenta colocar o  "event.preventDefault ()" na primeira linha da função increment, alias, coloca o event na declaração da função tb function increment(event)

Comment: testei aqui e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Não temos a certeza absoluta, mas, pelo seu problema apresentado faltou pegar `children` da sua `props` no componente `<Header />`, para renderizar qualquer funcionalidade sendo essas funções `javascript`, textos e objetos. Um exemplo que soluciona o problema de não apresentação do valor é a seguinte:

```js
function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.children}</div> // children
  )
}
function App() {
  const [count, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  function increment() {
    setCounter(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
       <Header>Contador: {count}</Header>
       <button onClick={increment}>Incrementar</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

<sup>**Referencias:**</sup>

- [React avançado — Utilizando “props.children” como função de primeira classe](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/react-avan%C3%A7ado-utilizando-props-children-como-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-primeira-classe-f6be8acdfaf1)
- [React This Props Children](https://learn.co/lessons/react-this-props-children)
- [A quick intro to React’s props.children](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891)